# OMP Atomic Assignment to Pointer Location and Pointer Increment

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, atomic

I have a need (particle binning) for multiple threads in a OMP SMP parallel region to determine which array to write data to and then increment a counter to track how much data has been written. The data is evenly distributed but randomly ordered and the number of output arrays is not known a priori.

I can't seem to come up with a way to atomically write and update the counters together (or increment the bin pointer) at the same time. I feel like this should be possible with OMP atomics and without using #omp critical which would kill performance.

```
int** bins ...
int* bin_counters ...

#pragma omp parallel for 
for(int i = 0; i < n_particles; i++) {
    int bin_index = calc_bin(particles[i]);

    // Something here to prevent write clashes
    int* bin = bins[bin_index]
    bin[bin_counters++] = i;

}
```

Comment: Can you give each thread its own set of bins, and concatenate them at the end?  (Either with a single thread or a prefix-sum of lengths to figure out where each thread should copy each bin to.)  I don't know how you'd tell OpenMP to do that for you, but it's probably much better unless you have a huge number of bins so contention is very rare and copying them is expensive.  The extra copying is less bad than having to use an atomic RMW increment to get a new write position; on x86-64 an atomic RMW is a full memory barrier so it destroys memory-level parallelism in the main loop.

Comment: I have about 4.5 million bins and 128 threads so individual copies is somewhat memory prohibitive. My current implementation stores each bin index in an array of length n_particle, then each thread runs through it and copies only particles to bins that are assigned to that thread. The downside is each thread needs to read through all particles despite that average number of particles per bin being pretty low most of the time.

Comment: I see.  Redundant reads and redundant computation might well be the best tradeoff, especially on x86 where you can't do atomic increments without a huge penalty in memory parallelism which is obviously important for scattered stores.  (And scattered RMWs).  Hmm, maybe a batch of loads and then a batch of write-prefetches (`prefetchw`), before doing a batch of actual atomic increments (of per-bin counters) to get write indices?  Then do a batch of stores to bins. That's still correct on contention, but may be faster in the no-contention case.

Comment: How many particles do you have per bin? Since you store particle indices in the bins, duplicating the bins may not actually be that bad (memory consumption may be dominated by the indices). Besides, 4.5 million bins isn't that much. If you store 1 `std::vector` per bin, that's just 102 MiB. 100 MiB per thread is not nothing, but it's also not the end of the world.

Answer (score 1):

The standard thing would be an array of `std::atomic<uint32_t> bin_pos[n_bins]` (or `atomic<size_t>`) write-positions, where you do an atomic increment to claim the next place in that bin.

You start with the array of write-positions initialized to zero, so the first thread to write that bin will write to the start of the bin array.  It's ok if multiple threads manage to claim slots in a bin before any of them finish storing to those slots; a sequence of `var.fetch_add(1)` or `var++` will produce every number from `0` to `n` once, so exactly one thread will be writing each array.  C++ guarantees that separate threads accessing separate array elements is thread-safe.

```
   std::atomic<uint32_t> bin_pos[n_bins];

   ...
   int *bin = bins[index];
   size_t pos = bin_pos[index].fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
   bin[pos] = i;
```

I don't know how to tell OpenMP to do that for you; I wouldn't be surprised if there's a convenient way.

**But this sucks for performance, probably worse than what you're doing now.**  It's a big problem on x86-64 where an atomic RMW is a full memory barrier, so it destroys memory-level parallelism.  The scattered stores are likely to cache miss, separate from the RMW itself.  But the next increment is a full barrier so it has to wait for that store to commit.  And also of course blocking loads of the next `bin_pos` counter from starting; you'd want multiple of those in flight to each core.

Also, atomic RMW itself is quite slow, like 1 per 20 clock cycles best case on current x86 (data already exclusively owned in L1d cache of the current core.)  https://uops.info/ and https://agner.org/optimize/, look for `lock add` or `lock inc`.

---

#### Brainstorming ideas that might be less slow (especially on x86)

I'm kind of assuming that most HPC work happens on x86 hardware; if you actually have PowerPC or AArch64 that could make relaxed atomic RMWs much less bad.

Can you give each thread its own set of bins and concatenate them at the end? (Either with a single thread or a prefix-sum of lengths to figure out where each thread should copy each bin to.)

I don't know how you'd tell OpenMP to do that for you either, but if your bins aren't too numerous or huge it's probably much better.

> I have about 4.5 million bins and 128 threads so individual copies is somewhat memory prohibitive. My current implementation stores each bin index in an array of length `n_particle`, then each thread runs through it and copies only particles to bins that are assigned to that thread. The downside is each thread needs to read through all particles despite that average number of particles per bin being pretty low most of the time.

Redundant reads and redundant computation might well be the best tradeoff, especially on x86 where you can't do atomic increments without a huge penalty in memory parallelism which is obviously important for scattered stores.  (And scattered RMWs).

Recomputing the bin index from the particle data might not be the worst thing, but if each particle is many more than 8 bytes then yeah, spreading that work across threads saves aggregate memory bandwidth.  Getting the same data from L3 cache to multiple threads might not be that bad, but this could be worth the extra pass over the data, especially since the scattered stores will create a lot of cache-miss traffic.

---

#### Perhaps some software prefetching and batching work together

For the atomic `fetch_add` strategy like you're asking about, and the top of this answer:

Maybe do a batch of loads (into 8 or so local variables) and then a batch of write-prefetches (`prefetchw`), before doing a batch of actual atomic increments (of per-bin counters) to get write indices?  Then do a batch of stores to bins. That's still correct on contention (if two threads both `prefetchw` the same counter), but may be faster in the no-contention case.

It could allow the RFOs (Read For Ownership) for a batch of counters to overlap. And same for the plain stores to the bins because you'd be doing for example 8 plain stores between the last `fetch_add` in one batch and the first `fetch_add` in the next.

---

#### Other ideas:

- Use fewer threads so we can afford to replicate the bins?  Probably not good.  But do keep in mind that the max size needed for each bin is only `n_particles/threads`, not the full `n_particles`, unless you have some way to set a tighter upper bound on space per bin.  (If you were using `realloc`, that won't be thread-safe.)
- Or groups of threads sharing a subset of bins?  (Without precomputing write indices, instead skipping writes to bins that aren't in the subset this group is working on. So with 4 groups, each particle gets read and index computed 4 times, by one thread in each of the 4 groups.)   But any sharing of bins means you need atomics, and the problem isn't contention for bins, it's the atomics themselves.

Could we maybe take a lock on the array of position counters for that group, do multiple increments, then unlock and write to the bin array?  That's probably bad, too coarse grained.  Maybe look at a bunch of particles and partially sort by bin, so we can have a lock for the first 1/128th of the bins, the 2nd 128th of the bins, etc.  So hopefully we could get fine-grained locking, but still create a decent amount of increments to do per lock/unlock, within that range of locked bins.  (Each thread might have an array of scratch space for this partial sorting.)

- Or partition the particle list somehow so particles that are definitely somewhere in the first half of your bins can only get looked at by those threads?

Maybe do a coarser first-stage binning into fewer per-thread bins, then have another pass where threads bin within those bins?  This is kind of like Radix Sort.  I'm not sure how exactly that could help, or what temporary data-structures you'd want for it.

---

#### Reserve space for multiple elements per atomic `fetch_add` RMW

- **Let multiple writers store into their own chunk of the bin most of the time, to be compacted later.**  This can amortize the cost of the atomic `fetch_add` counter increments over multiple particles so a good fraction of them are cheap non-atomic.

Like maybe when adding a particle to a bin, reserve a chunk of space (e.g. 8 or 16 particles) for this thread in that bin, so an atomic RMW is only needed on average every 8 or 16 particles to get another chunk.  (Assuming the typical particles per bin per thread isn't like 1 or 9 or something.)

Each thread needs a private array of offsets into bins; if `pos % chunksize == 0` then we need to do an atomic fetch_add on the shared array of counts to reserve another 8 which we might or might not fill by the end.  Bins will be densely packed up to the first group a thread left unfilled.

Compaction at the end would have to examine each thread's bookkeeping arrays, unless the bin arrays can be initialized with a sentinel value that isn't a particle id.  e.g. `-1` if you can use signed integers (although that means writing all bin memory, no lazy allocation for untouched pages.)  Or to allow freshly zeroed memory from the kernel to work for this (`calloc`, `mmap`, or static arrays that aren't reused), we could do the first particle (`0`) separately (before threading) so we know it's definitely at the start of one of the bins, and any `0` later is unused space.  Or do particle `0` at the *end*, after compacting (tacking it on to the end of some bin), so we don't have to special case anything during compaction.

With a sentinel, it's just left-packing based on the data, which AVX-512 is very good at (`vpcompactd`).  But with AVX2 or earlier, you'd want to look at the bookkeeping to figure out ranges to `memmove`.  (Each thread leaves at most one partially filled group so the bookkeeping data isn't too bad to process).

If order doesn't matter, **you don't need to copy all later elements to fill gaps**, just loop through the gaps near the start of the array, and copy elements from the end of the bin to fill those gaps, removing them from the end.  So again you'd definitely want to use the bookkeeping data to find elements near the end of array and find the earlier gaps to be filled.

```
using partidx_type = uint32_t;    // or size_t if we can have a lot of particles
using binpos_type = uint32_t;     // or size_t if each bins can be huge

// global state
partidx_type bins[n_bins][MAXBINSIZE];       // or equivalent dynamically allocated
std::atomic<binpos_type> shared_binpos[n_bins];  // or make this non-atomic and have the threaded part use atomic_ref, so the cleanup code can use non-atomic accesses to it.

static constexpr unsigned groupsize = 8;

// per-thread private state
struct thread_positions {
    binpos_type nextwrite_pos[n_bins] = {};
    // that's all for now, doesn't actually need a struct.
}thread_data[nthreads];

/// called in each thread
void count(int TID, ...)
{
   ...
   // auto *nextwrite_pos = thread_data[TID].nextwrite_pos;
   for (i) {
       binpos_type index = calc_bin(particles[i]);
       partidx_type *bin = bins[index];
    
       size_t pos = thread_data[TID].nextwrite_pos[index];
       if (pos % groupsize == 0) {  // unsigned power-of-2 modulo is very cheap
           // we're past the end of the group we owned; reserve another
           pos = shared_binpos[index].fetch_add(groupsize, std::memory_order_relaxed);
       }
       bin[pos] = i;
       thread_data[TID].nextwrite_pos[index] = pos+1;
   }
}
```

This *will* have significant branch-misprediction as well as cache misses, so hyperthreading will probably help.  But branch misses stall for less time than cache misses, so it's probably worth the price to let out-of-order exec loose on overlapping memory operations.

When we're done, `shared_binpos[index]` holds the position of the start of the last group in the `index`ed bin.  For some thread-ID, `thread_data[TID].nextwrite_pos[index]` will be 1 past that position, from which you can see how many of the `groupsize` elements were actually written.

If we do particle `0` after compaction, and the bins were zeroed to start with, it's easy to do some left-packing of the likely-sparse groups at the end of the bin just based on the data, giving you a pool of elements to pull from as you loop over TIDs to find the earlier gaps in this bin to fill in.

Every `groupsize` group of elements in the bin before `shared_binpos[index]` will have at least one written element.  (And up to `groupsize-1` gaps, but the number of groups with gaps is limited to `n_threads`.  If there are more groups than that, some of them will be full.)

If the total number of particle per bin across all threads is still fairly small, this compaction work would be relatively expensive.  It does parallelize nicely, with a bin or group of bins assigned to a worker thread.

---

We could use different data structure for bins, like an array of `struct bin_group { int used_count; uint32_t particles[7]; };`  (Or `size_t` / `uint64_t` for particle indices if you can't use 32-bit integers.)  Compaction would be a matter of loading structs and copying `group.particles[0..used_count-1]` to the final array for each bin.

Instead of actual structs, it would also possible to keep a C++ compiler happy by just using `uint32_t bin[]` and having the element where `i%8 == 0` be special, a count of later elements.  That would allow in-place compaction without placement-new shenanigans.

But I don't know if that inline bookkeeping is better; it means more elements have to move to compact things.  (The same trick of pulling elements from the end of the array works, but writing 1 int per 8 still means dirtying the cache line.  So it's worse in that respect if there tend to be a significant number of completed groups before you start getting to partial groups.)

Comment: `#pragma omp atomic capture` is the OpenMP equivalent of `fetch_add`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all: don't do that `int*` and `int**` stuff. That's not proper modern C++. Use containers.

With proper C++ programming your problem is easy to solve: make a `histogram` class that contains the histogram, and overload `operator+` for your histogram class. Then you can solve your problem as an OpenMP reduction: each thread constructs its own histogram, and because of the overloaded addition operator they nicely get added together.

Comment: This isn't just a histogram.  They want to be able to iterate over the particles that went into each bin later, so they need a container of indices, not just a counter, for each bin.  If you mean making a class that atomically increments a counter *and* stores an element at the resulting array position, then yeah that could do what they asked for in the question.  But that's probably not very fast, as I described in the first section of my answer, at least not on x86 CPUs because they can't do atomic RMWs without a full memory barrier.

Comment: @PeterCordes My approach still works. Make a histogram class that not only counts but stores the data. Overload the plus operator to merge histograms. Do a reduction. None of that requires atomic operations because in an OMP reduction each thread gets a local copy of the reduced-into object.